# Integrating Paypal button with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal in my rails application by generating a hosted button from paypal. I am following the following guide https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/buy_now_step_1/ but I cannot find a way to dynamically generate a buy now button with custom prices and description without first creating it through paypal.com.

My question is is there a way to generate the buttons dynamically from my database of items so that they don't have to be first created through paypal.com manually.

or

Is there a better way to do this? I'm new to both rails and paypal API.